# Change value of dynamic inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal window that has a lot of new dynamic elements (inputs, buttons, etc.). I want to see if a certain element(or in this case, and input) gets created and if it does, then change its value.

The scenario is that if I make an ajax request for populating data, and as the user browses the modal window I can reuse some of that data. When the input field I'm looking for gets created, I can just put the value of the ajax call I made previously.

I have tried: `$("#myinput_id").val(sellerData['id']);`

obviously the above wont work because the element doesn't exists, yet. I'm also trying to avoid new ajax calls for the same data :/

Any thoughts?

```
  $( "#add").bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/seller/get',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(response) {
        sellerData = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

        //other code here

        //this doesn't work
        $("#myinput_id").val(sellerData['id']);
      }
    });
  });
```

Then the above gets triggers. The input field doesn't exist yet. How can I make it "look for it" if in the future the input field gets created?

Comment: Could you post some more code?  Why can't you change the value after you add the element to the DOM?

Comment: updated my code to include where I'm calling things. Note that everyone is working fine, it's just that I can make it search for the input field if it ever gets created.

Comment: What is the error that you get ?

Comment: I don't get any errors because this is valid code. This code just assumes that the input field myinput_id already exists. I'm trying to find a solution that looks for the input when it gets created down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.length` http://api.jquery.com/length/

```
if($("#myinput_id").length) //There is at least one element selected
    //Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit confusing question you are saying u want to populate the data and your are using **POST**

Comment: this is why I didn't want to post more code because it is confusing. Ignore the post, I'm just trying to change the value of a "future" input field that hasn't yet been generated.

Comment: Confusing or not, the code you posted isn't enough for anyone to tell what's really going on unfortunately...